# Sharepoint 2013 running ultra slow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sql-server

Any help appreciated.

We have a single farm SharePoint 2013 environment. We have had issues intermittently with ultra-slowness. Previously the issue was the crawl configuration which is now sorted along with our alternate mapping. The current load times are extensive for first time load as subsequent loads 30 – 60 seconds. Nothing that appears out of the ordinary -default page is made up of a number of web parts (no list webview parts). We have used the developers dashboard to give more information as to what is happening on the WFE.

Our environment is built on Virtual Servers - 2012 r2 servers * 2. One for the SP2013 install and another which holds the SQL database (16 GB Memory, 4 cores, 300GB storage on both). We are trying to pinpoint the issue/s. I do notice our Sharepoint_config_log is currently over 20GB. All our SQL logs seem large but not sure if this is normal for SP. We have looked at a number of articles to assist but the information seems wide and varied. Suggestions to turn of the Distributed Cache (we do not want to do this – need it for virtual server), assign more memory, stop continuous crawls – none of which seem to fit our issue.

Need a guidance here.

Comment: What is the CPU and memory utilization on all servers? Do you observe any continuous spikes? Was the slowness observed on OOB pages like settings page, central admin or it is only custom pages? Slowness observed while opening pages within the server or only while accessing outside the server?

Comment: The CPU is fine - 136GB - ballooning spread across. The slowness occurs on the server, central admin and on the server

Comment: Is anyone able to tell me if it is normal for the Sharepoint_config_log to be over 20GB